# Unable to access published website after upgrade from Tridion 2009SP1 to 2013SP1

Tags: 2013, dynamic-linking

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
<JavaException>
    <Type>java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError</Type>
    <Message><![CDATA[Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking
============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

============================================================

 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPARatingDAO
 com.tridion.preview.web.util.HandleSessionContentUtil
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtensionType
 com.tridion.validation.adapter.ContentValidatorSpringAdapter
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.InvalidTokenException
 com.tridion.validation.ValidationFacade
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenProcessor
 com.tridion.web.asp.ASPAdmin
 com.tridion.marketingsolution.profilesync.Handler
 com.tridion.linking.Linking
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Rating
 com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper
 com.tridion.validation.ValidationException
 com.tridion.webservices.linking.LinkingService
 com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.BinaryLinkingAdaptor
 com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStoreProvider
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataRequestContext
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCValidationFacade
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler
 com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter
 com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.ComponentLinkingAdaptor
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Comment
 com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.PageLinkingAdaptor
 com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.DynamicComponentLinkingAdaptor
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAUserDAO
 com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp$Error
 com.tridion.webservices.security.validator.OAuth2RequestValidator
 com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleCommentingValidator
 com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor
 com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleRatingValidator
 com.tridion.preview.web.BinaryContentHandler
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchResponse
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessToken
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPACommentDAO
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataResponse
 com.tridion.util.HttpStatusCodes
 com.tridion.ugc.Status
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAItemStatsDAO
 com.tridion.linking.ASPLinking
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataMediaType
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCConfigurationLoader
 com.tridion.web.Admin
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.User
 com.tridion.preview.web.PageHandler
 [Lcom.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtensionType;
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2ResponseMessage
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.ItemStats
 com.tridion.preview.web.util.AmbientDataUtil
 com.tridion.util.ServiceExtensionException
 [Lcom.tridion.ugc.Status;
 [Lcom.tridion.util.HttpStatusCodes;
 com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Item
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.RatingDAO
 com.tridion.validation.ContentValidator
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataServiceOperation
 com.tridion.validation.Errors
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.UserDAO
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtension
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataWritableEntryService
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataResourceBundleRegistrationService
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.CommentDAO
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataWritableStreamEntryService
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.ItemStatsDAO

]]></Message>
    <StackTrace><![CDATA[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking
at com.tridion.linking.AbstractLink.<init>(AbstractLink.java:69)
at com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.<init>(ComponentLink.java:84)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
  at Com.Tridion.Linking.ComponentLink..ctor(Int32 publicationId)
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI.ComponentLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at ASP.master_master.__RenderbodyTag(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in e:\Websites\za\Master.master:line 401
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)]]></StackTrace>
</JavaException>
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

```
Java.Lang.Throwable:     
<JavaException>
        <Type>java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError</Type>
        <Message><![CDATA[Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking
============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

============================================================

 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPARatingDAO
 com.tridion.preview.web.util.HandleSessionContentUtil
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtensionType
 com.tridion.validation.adapter.ContentValidatorSpringAdapter
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.InvalidTokenException
 com.tridion.validation.ValidationFacade
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenProcessor
 com.tridion.web.asp.ASPAdmin
 com.tridion.marketingsolution.profilesync.Handler
 com.tridion.linking.Linking
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Rating
 com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper
 com.tridion.validation.ValidationException
 com.tridion.webservices.linking.LinkingService
 com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.BinaryLinkingAdaptor
 com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStoreProvider
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataRequestContext
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCValidationFacade
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler
 com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter
 com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.ComponentLinkingAdaptor
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Comment
 com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.PageLinkingAdaptor
 com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.DynamicComponentLinkingAdaptor
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAUserDAO
 com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp$Error
 com.tridion.webservices.security.validator.OAuth2RequestValidator
 com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleCommentingValidator
 com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor
 com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleRatingValidator
 com.tridion.preview.web.BinaryContentHandler
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchResponse
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessToken
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPACommentDAO
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataResponse
 com.tridion.util.HttpStatusCodes
 com.tridion.ugc.Status
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAItemStatsDAO
 com.tridion.linking.ASPLinking
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataMediaType
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCConfigurationLoader
 com.tridion.web.Admin
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.User
 com.tridion.preview.web.PageHandler
 [Lcom.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtensionType;
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2ResponseMessage
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.ItemStats
 com.tridion.preview.web.util.AmbientDataUtil
 com.tridion.util.ServiceExtensionException
 [Lcom.tridion.ugc.Status;
 [Lcom.tridion.util.HttpStatusCodes;
 com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor
 com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Item
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.RatingDAO
 com.tridion.validation.ContentValidator
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataServiceOperation
 com.tridion.validation.Errors
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.UserDAO
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtension
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataWritableEntryService
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataResourceBundleRegistrationService
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.CommentDAO
 com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataWritableStreamEntryService
 com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.ItemStatsDAO

]]></Message>
        <StackTrace><![CDATA[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking
at com.tridion.linking.AbstractLink.<init>(AbstractLink.java:69)
at com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.<init>(ComponentLink.java:84)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
  at Com.Tridion.Linking.ComponentLink..ctor(Int32 publicationId)
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI.ComponentLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at ASP.master_master.__RenderbodyTag(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in e:\Websites\za\Master.master:line 401
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)]]></StackTrace>
</JavaException>
```

Source Error:

Line 399:
 Line 400:
 Line 401:">Sitemap
 Line 402:
 Line 403:

Source File: e:\Websites\za\Master.master    Line: 401

Stack Trace:

```
Throwable: 
<JavaException>
        <Type>java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError</Type>
        <Message><![CDATA[Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking
============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

 - you forgot to configure a classpath
 - a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
   classpath
 - you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
 - a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
   your classpath
 - a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
   contain some new classes

============================================================

  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPARatingDAO
  com.tridion.preview.web.util.HandleSessionContentUtil
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtensionType
  com.tridion.validation.adapter.ContentValidatorSpringAdapter
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.InvalidTokenException
  com.tridion.validation.ValidationFacade
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenProcessor
  com.tridion.web.asp.ASPAdmin
  com.tridion.marketingsolution.profilesync.Handler
  com.tridion.linking.Linking
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Rating
  com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper
  com.tridion.validation.ValidationException
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.LinkingService
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.BinaryLinkingAdaptor
  com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStoreProvider
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataRequestContext
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCValidationFacade
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler
  com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.ComponentLinkingAdaptor
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Comment
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.PageLinkingAdaptor
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.DynamicComponentLinkingAdaptor
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAUserDAO
  com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp$Error
  com.tridion.webservices.security.validator.OAuth2RequestValidator
  com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleCommentingValidator
  com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp
  com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor
  com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleRatingValidator
  com.tridion.preview.web.BinaryContentHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchResponse
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessToken
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPACommentDAO
  com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataResponse
  com.tridion.util.HttpStatusCodes
  com.tridion.ugc.Status
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAItemStatsDAO
  com.tridion.linking.ASPLinking
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataMediaType
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCConfigurationLoader
  com.tridion.web.Admin
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.User
  com.tridion.preview.web.PageHandler
  [Lcom.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtensionType;
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2ResponseMessage
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.ItemStats
  com.tridion.preview.web.util.AmbientDataUtil
  com.tridion.util.ServiceExtensionException
  [Lcom.tridion.ugc.Status;
  [Lcom.tridion.util.HttpStatusCodes;
  com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Item
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.RatingDAO
  com.tridion.validation.ContentValidator
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataServiceOperation
  com.tridion.validation.Errors
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.UserDAO
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtension
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataWritableEntryService
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataResourceBundleRegistrationService
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.CommentDAO
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataWritableStreamEntryService
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.ItemStatsDAO

]]></Message>
        <StackTrace><![CDATA[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking
    at com.tridion.linking.AbstractLink.<init>(AbstractLink.java:69)
    at com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.<init>(ComponentLink.java:84)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
   at Com.Tridion.Linking.ComponentLink..ctor(Int32 publicationId)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI.ComponentLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at ASP.master_master.__RenderbodyTag(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in e:\Websites\za\Master.master:line 401
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)]]></StackTrace>
</JavaException>
```

Stacktrace:

```
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex) +88
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst) +329
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1009
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args) +681
   Com.Tridion.Linking.ComponentLink..ctor(Int32 publicationId) +206
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI.ComponentLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +193
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +249
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +249
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +395
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +49
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   ASP.master_master.__RenderbodyTag(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in e:\Websites\za\Master.master:401
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +131
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +49
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +249
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +249
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5363
```

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET

Version:4.0.30319.18408

Comment: do you have updated DLLs and Jars of 2013sp1 with correct 32/64 version in bin?

Comment: Please do not just post an error message/log. You will get a more helpful response if you phrase your question as an actual question, stating what you did and what you have tried in order to fix the problem already.

Comment: This type of question might not get interest from most of the community as posting a error message would not help. It would be great if you post what is your scenario, what you have analyzed so far and instead of posting the whole big error stack trace ... what are relevant error in the various Tridion Logs..it will help community to help you better

Comment: CM & CD was migrated from Tridion 2009 SP1 to Tridion 2013 SP1 successfully. There is not problem with CM/CD. I published the Home Page of one of my Website and some dependent User Controls, I have updated .Net DLLs with current Tridion Classes. All set. Now when I try to browse my website, I get the following error.

Comment: Yes....raj-kumar ... I have updated to the current DLLs, Custom DLLs & Jars. I am using 64bit env.

Comment: I am not sure....but I feel that there is a missing JAR. Does anyone knows where to find a documentation mentioning the functionality of all the JARs for Tridion.

Comment: there is an option in app pool enable 32 bit: set it false, and try again. if still unresolved, Configure logback.xml in Verbose mode and check if you get more information about the missing jar/class.

Comment: Thanks Raj....I will try this out and let you know....can you please mention why should I make my app pool to 32 bit?

Comment: @SoumyaGhosh - When you say "CM & CD was migrated from Tridion 2009 SP1 to Tridion 2013 SP1 successfully.", does this mean that your site was working correctly before you republished the homepage?

Comment: @JonathanWilliams We didnt migrate the Website. Thought to publish it instead. Rest of CM & CD, except the Website was fine. Previously we had Deployer Windows Service. But now we are using the Web Service of the Deployer.

Answer (score 2):

Reading through your stack trace, you may have the UGC bundle enabled in your storage Conf, but missing the jars for it (or vice versa). Given that you're upgrading from 2009, I can guarantee you don't need UGC.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your environment, what you have upgraded and how, it is difficult to help.

It looks like you have issues with the Content Delivery JARs in your application. This is not completely unexpected, as quite a lot has changed since 2009SP1.

I would first look at the online documentation's [Upgrading the Content Delivery Server Roles](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-C2C269FD-B689-4292-BD85-20405C1238E2) section (login required), which has sub-sections explaining what JARs to add, update and remove as part of an upgrade and double check that everything had been upgraded according to the instructions.

Also take a look through [Upgrading Content Delivery .NET Server Roles](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9E6A3364-4102-4550-A643-D4D01B049695).